# Dialogflow Fulfillment - Mutiple Intents

Tags: dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I need some help in creating the fulfillment for the intents that  i have created in Dialog flow. There are 15 intents that i have created and i have integrated them and tested and it works fine. I am stuck in fulfillment and unable to proceed since i am confused whether the fulfillment setup. Since has to be done for every intent that i have created i believe. I am unsure how to do this to complete by one click using fulfillment link on the left pane. does it work if i just directly click on fulfillment and deploy. I am really confused. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Fulfillment is a multi-step process.

**Enabling Fulfillment**

1. Select Fulfillment on the left navigation
2. If your fulfillment code will be running at a remote webhook, enable "Webhook" and enter the URL for your webhook.
3. If you don't have a place to run your fulfillment code, you can also use the Inline Editor to get started. Enable this, and you'll be entering your code here directly.
4. Save the configuration.

[image: Illustration of steps to enable fulfillment]

**Enabling for each Intent**

While this sets the Fulfillment that will be used for your project, you must still enable this for *each* Intent that should call it.

1. Go back to the Intent listing and select an Intent.
2. Scroll towards the bottom of the page in the Fulfillment section.
3. Turn "Enable webhook call for this intent" on.
4. Save the configuration.
5. Repeat this for *every* Intent that you want to process using Fulfillment.

[image: illustration of steps to enable for each Intent]

**Deploying your webhook**

You will also need to write your webhook to handle the various Intents that are triggered. The code for the Inline Editor can be a good place to start.

In the `intentMap`, you will need to add a map from the Intent name to a function that will do the handling when that Intent triggers the webhook. You can have a different handler function for each Intent, use the same function for some, have those functions call other functions, whatever you need.

A couple of things to note, however:

- If your handler needs to do an asynchronous function (access a database, make a network call, etc), then you need to make sure you return a Promise.
- If you're using the Inline Editor and you're making network calls outside of Google's network, then you need to upgrade your Firebase subscription to the Blaze plan. (You will still likely be able to work with the free tier of that plan.)

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function handlerOne(agent) {
    agent.add(`This is handler one`);
  }

  function handlerThree(agent) {
    agent.add(`This is handler three`);
  }


  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('intent.one', handlerOne);
  intentMap.set('intent.two', handlerOne);
  intentMap.set('intent.three', handlerThree);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map in the API, where all intent will be mapped to a correspondence handler in fulfillment.

Here is sample code,

```
const express = require("express");
const { WebhookClient } = require("dialogflow-fulfillment");
const { welcome, defaultFallback } = require("./intents/welcomeExit");
const app = express();
app.post("/dialogflow", express.json(), (req, res) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set("Default Welcome Intent", welcome);
    intentMap.set("Default Fallback Intent", defaultFallback);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

This has been done in NodeJS. You can use other languages supported by Dialogflow.
How it gets configured in Dialogflow check this [link](https://medium.com/@abhinavkumar985/nodejs-webhook-for-dialogflow-fulfillment-a8e392b257b8).